# Jenkins waitForQualityGate wrong id

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to integrate Sonarqube in my Jenkins pipeline, all works fine untile gateway checks.

> ```
>     stage('Sonar') {
>         steps {
>             withSonarQubeEnv(installationName: 'Sonarqube', credentialsId: 'sonar') {
>             sh "$SCANNER_HOME/bin/sonar-scanner -D'sonar.projectKey=$JOB_NAME'"
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     stage("Quality Gate") {
>         steps {
>           timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
>             waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
>           }
>         }
>     }
> ```

withSonarQubeEnv reports an id, for example: AXyPGkHZtOM2BAFbSUcX . Using `api/ce/task?id=AXyPGkHZtOM2BAFbSUcX` I can see process status and analysisId(f.e. AXyPGkmqJtbgJ09MpQ6B)
The point is that waitForQualityGate alway reads `api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=AXyLfj5JlX0w7MRERt_e` resulting in a 404.
I'm on that from something like 5 h and can't get out.
Someone has ideas?

Comment: Consider moving the waitForQualityGate block to after the withSonarQubeEnv, in the same stage.

Answer (score 1):

The stages look fine, the HTTP 404 issue is due SonarQube not understanding the projectKey by the looks of it, from above you have`-D'sonar.projectKey=$JOB_NAME'` . The command & variable are defined incorrectly, it should be `-Dsonar.projectKey='$JOB_NAME'`.

That way the SonarQube server will be able to send analysis back to the Jenkins webhook with the correct key

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I moved sonarcube temp files to another location. Those changes reflect on Jenkins too but plug-in can't handle that so it was looking for file before the temp-dir change.